# Yii framework module routing through URL

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, module

I have this already developed project on Yii and the problem is that the modules are not accessible via URLs. So, I went to my /config/main.php to see the URL manager code. it is like:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
'caseSensitive'=>false,
    ),
```

EDIT: Added `'caseSensitive'=>false,`

and the modules section is like

```
'modules'=>array(
    'api_v1',   
    'api_s1',
),
```

Inside modules I have folders for both and they again have controllers folder. The controller under controllers folder is ServerController.php with action functions like
    actionList

but when I go to access this module I type in the browser as:

```
http://domain-name/api_s1/server/List
```

but it is showing `404` error. I am not sure what else is required. Any help will be highly appreciated.

## EDITED:

I have a `.htaccess` file in every main folder as in `protected`, `framework` and in the main folder also. All `.htaccess` files have only one line as
    deny form all

but the main `.htaccess` file which is on the root has this

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

Comment: try 'caseSensitive'  => false

Comment: no it is also not working. I am not sure, i am missing any thing? I checked and everywhere it is like this. Please see

Comment: Do you have .htaccess?

Comment: if yes then the posiblity is like you've to change List to list in LINUX since its case sensitive

Comment: I have other actions also which are not working like mostRating. so same will be applied for all?

Comment: so index.php is deactivated right? like 'showScriptName' => false?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like

```
http://domain-name/index.php/api_s1/server/List
```

Hope you did not use `.htaccess` coz if you are using .htaccess you have to mention

"showScriptName" => false

in the `urlManager` in `config/main.php` to remove `index.php` from your URL

**Edited :** 
Again try adding these to your `urlManager`

```
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>',
    '<module:\w+>' => '<module>',
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have .htaccess in main folder and also in protected and framwork folder. Updated question, please see the edited section.

Answer (score 1):

hope this could help you

```
'urlManager'=>array(

                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'showScriptName'=>false,
'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
                array('api/controller/action/', 'api/controller/action', 'caseSensitive'=>false, 'verb'=>'GET'),
                )
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this is also not working. Seems it may be because of the htaccess file. Please see mey edited question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

please add this code to your .htaccess hope this could help you

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
        .htaccess file should conatain(in Root folder of your project along with index.php)
        RewriteEngine on

        # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        # otherwise forward it to index.php
        RewriteRule . index.php


        In main.php
        urlManager'=>array("showScriptName" => false 
                            'caseSensitive'=>false,   
                            'showScriptName'=>false,

                                       ),
    Hope this helps.



   you have also mentioned you have more than one .htaccess files so to get more clarity also refer
    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63114/two-htaccess-files-located-in-different-directories
```